# winjs angular typescript with splitView

Tags: angularjs, typescript, winjs

I'm trying to use winjs with angular and typescript.
The Angular-Winjs wrapper is working good as long I don't have to use some additional JavaScript for the Dom-Elements.

In my case I want to use the split-view item:
The menu gets displayed but the JavaScript-functionallity is not working.

this is my Code:

```
<win-split-view-pane-toggle split-view="splitViewElement"></win-split-view-pane-toggle>
<win-split-view id="splitView">
    <win-split-view-pane>
        SplitView Navigation Pane
        <win-split-view-command label="'Home'" icon="'home'" on-invoked="goToHome()"></win-split-view-command>
        <win-split-view-command label="'Settings'" icon="'settings'" on-invoked="goToSettings()"></win-split-view-command>
    </win-split-view-pane>
    <win-split-view-content>SplitView Content Area</win-split-view-content>
</win-split-view>
```

this is the example Code from the github-project-side.

their example also says that I have to add this to my Controller:

```
angular.module("yourAngularApp", ["winjs"]).controller("yourController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.splitViewElement = document.getElementById("splitView");
});
```

now my problem is that I'm using typescript and create my Controller with the controllerAs-Syntax. When I add

```
$scope.splitViewElement = document.getElementById("splitView");
```

to my controller, the splitView-Element is NULL.

I also tried to use

```
angular.element("splitView").context
```

which has an element but it doesn't work, too.

this is my Controller.

```
constructor($scope, $state, $http, $q) {
    super($state, $http, $q, $scope, true);

    $scope.splitViewElement = document.getElementById("splitView"); //this is null
    $scope.splitViewElement = angular.element("splitView").context; //this is not null

        }
```

Comment: Given the fact the library is not so widespread, I would ask the author: https://github.com/winjs/angular-winjs/issues

Comment: @Martin: yes that is what I did today. I contacted them via nuget...hopefully they will answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might be late but here is how it works for me. In my controller I'm querying for the element with angular.element

`vm.splitViewElement = angular.element("#splitView")[0];`

If the element is available it should be the first in the array. Now simply bind the vm.splitViewElement to your view:

```
<win-split-view-pane-toggle class="win-splitviewpanetoggle" split-view="vm.splitViewElement">
</win-split-view-pane-toggle>
```